# PHP unwanted characters removing solution

Tags: php, regex, string

In a description getting characters like "â��".

To convert those I tried with utf8_encode() it is converting this charterers to another weird pattern.Also tried with regx and by setting character 
 it didnt work.

Any quick solution to solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that? What should be there instead?

Comment: Needs much more info where the data comes from using what method using what encoding - it's likely there is an encoding mismatch at the root

Comment: why it gets an "minus" I am bit of confused!

Comment: @deceze I am getting it form an REST API and there those character will be "--"

Comment: It's simply impossible to answer this in a meaningful way without seeing some code and/or more detail.

Comment: It's simply some encoding problem. The API is returning data in one encoding and you're treating it as a different encoding, screwing up characters. We need more detail if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: I was trying to convert all the applicable characters to HTML entities using htmlentities,as why those character was found.after removing htmlentities its clean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your string contains characters encoded using the UTF-8
character set. UTF-8 has some multibyte characters. For example, the
Euro symbol `€` is represented in UTF-8 with the three bytes `E2,
82, AC`.

But your software is interpreting the string using a one-byte
encoding, such as ISO-8859-1. This causes each byte of the 3-byte
character to be interpreted as a separate character. `E2`, for
example, is being displayed as `â`, when it is actually only the
first byte of a 3-byte character.

utf8_encode() is not the solution to this. It takes an ISO-8859-1
encoded string and returns a UTF-8 string. You already have a UTF-8
string.

You have a couple of options.

One, fix whatever uses the string so that it expects the string to
contain UTF-8. That will properly preserve the characters that are
in the string. For example, if you are writing the string as part of
a web page, ensure that the webpage's character encoding is UTF-8.

Two, convert the string to whatever encoding you are actually using.
For example, you can convert the string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
with utf_decode(). The disadvantage is that ISO-8859-1 cannot
represent as many different characters as UTF-8, so some characters
will simply be lost in the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function that I wrote when I was dealing with utf8

```
function removeuni($content){
  preg_match_all("/[\x{80}-\x{3000}]/u", $content, $matches);

  foreach($matches[0] as $match){
    $content = str_replace($match, mb_convert_encoding($match, "HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8"), $content);
  }

  return $content;
}
```